# broken hyperlinks with memoir, caption, hyperref, sidecaption, and pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, captions, memoir

I am experiencing broken hyperlinks with `memoir` + `caption` + `hyperref` and the `sidecaption` environment in documents compiled with `pdflatex`. A MWE replicating my issue is below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

% create empty page for demonstration
\mbox{}
\clearpage

\begin{figure}
  \begin{sidecaption}{test}[test]
    test
  \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\ref{test} % link broken, links to first page

\end{document}
```

Compiling with `pdflatex` yields the warning

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{figure.0.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

and the hyperlink to the `sidecaption`ed figure is broken unless either (1) the `caption` package is not loaded or (2) a different engine such as `xelatex` is used.

I experience this behavior with other `sidecaption`ed floats as well. In a large, complex document (https://bayesoptbook.com/), hyperrefs are all working fine *except* those pointing to `sidecaption`ed floats – similar warnings on compilation, and similar broken hyperlinks linking to the top of the document.

Comment: it is an incompability between the caption package and memoir. When caption is loaded the name of the destination is `figure.caption.1` but the label doesn't store this. Probably this issue means that the author of caption is aware that there is a problem https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/112

Comment: With `\captionsetup{hypcap=false}`  it works, but you naturally loose the hypcap function.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the incompatibility seems to only affect floats with the `sidecaption` environment; hyperlinks to floats without `sidecaption` work fine with `memoir` + `caption` + `pdflatex`. This makes me hopeful that there may be a fix.

Comment: there is certainly a fix, but imho the author of the caption package will have to implement it, so make there a bug report.

Comment: But the `sidecaption` environment (where the problems appear to be localized) is implemented in the `memoir` class. I don't see how the author of `caption` could address the behavior of `sidecaption`. Perhaps I misunderstand the core issue.

Comment: without the caption package it works fine, but caption changes internally commands and so has to address also the sidecaption problem.

Comment: The `caption` author is now aware of this issue and working on a fix: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/112#note_1511338402

Answer (score 1):

The author of the `caption` package just implemented a fix: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/175, thanks to this question.

It is not released on CTAN yet, but you can already implement the fix by manually replacing a file on your system, namely `caption-memoir.sto`, with [this new version](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/blob/master/tex/caption-memoir.sto).
(For me, using Windows and TinyTeX, this file was located at `C:\TinyTeX\texmf-dist\tex\latex\caption\caption-memoir.sto`)

Comment: @rgarnett, the Bayes opt book internal links can be fixed now :)